# What is System.ContextBoundObject?

Tags: .net

What is [ContextBoundObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.contextboundobject.aspx) used for? The documentation mentions 'contexts', which seem to be programatically defined, but fails to give any explanation as to what one is.

Comment: It's an atrocity. It's paved with pitfalls. I don't see a reason to use it, but it makes an interesting read: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Synchronization_Contexts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the base class providing facilities for synchronization domains in .NET (a little known feature in since .NET 1.0)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569749.aspx

http://www.ddj.com/architect/184405771

Answer (score 4):

[This explanation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tilovell/2011/02/06/contextboundobject-part-1-making-contexts/) sounds completely different than the accepted answer, but it makes more intuitive sense:

> So what about `ContextBoundObject`?
>
> Firstly, it allows you to do everything you can do with `MarshalByRef` object. Secondly, it allows you to do *more*. You can take control over the details of control over object creation, proxy creation, and marshalling method calls.