# Create anonymous class that implements an interface

Tags: c#

I am wondering if there is some inline short way of creating a class implementing a interface. Just like there are the anonymous methods but with implementing interfaces.

The problem is:

```
interface iSomeInterface
{
  void DoIt();
}

public void myMethod(iSomeInterface param)
{
 ...
}
```

And I would like to use it like this:

```
object.myMethod(new { override DoIt() { Console.WriteLine("yay"); } } : iSomeInterface);
```

Any ideas?

Sorry in case its a duplicate.

Comment: `Func<T>` and `Action<T>` and their variants may be useful for you to achive something similar...

Comment: You could use Moq - it would be a gross abuse of it's purpose, but it would allow you to create what are essentially anonymous classes.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria My need is inline declaring a class with interface implementation. Else I would have to write a new business object that implements the interface.

Comment: Yes i understand this, what i didn't understood is WHY you want to create inline classes, what you gain instead of using other solutions (like Action of Func how suggested by @VS1

Comment: This isn't meant as mean or rude - really...  But I would at least like to suggest that you stop trying to find 'ninja like tricky trick's in code to do things...  Especially that 1 liner - almost made me scream...  really..  As a person that does application support (works on old and new projects, sometimes without documentation), things where I am sure the developer thought what they were doing was REALLY COOL, end up usually being the point where a bug creeps in..  On top of that, it is hard to maintain, and hard to come back to after a while and know WTF you just did.

Comment: @tostringtheory no offence but its a question, the world aint gonna end because of a one liner. The annonymous types are also ment to be used for small pojo's so you dont have to create a complete class because you will only use it once anyways in a method and then gc will collect it. Nobody would ever create a annonymous type and place 40 properties in it anyways.

Comment: @ninjahedgehog To solve this in c#, it would not be a one liner. Dont be so lazy, create a new class. In the time it took you to write, maintain and comment on this stack, you could have written all the code you would need.

Comment: @tostringtheory the interface is IWeakEventListener and it has one method called ReceiveEvent. its microsoft interface so i have to use it. i havent designed it. i have to use it but i didnt want to create a public/internal class for it because i really need it at just one place only once and then gc may collect it. anyways its a question. lets not turn this into discussion

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a C# anonymous class implement an interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191013/can-a-c-sharp-anonymous-class-implement-an-interface)

Comment: @tostringtheory almost 10 years later and it still hurts that this core feature is missing from C#. We now have dozens of fake classes litering the codebase (and often getting used in the wrong place, wrong way, or accidentally edited etc) just because you can't pass e.g. a Comparer to Dictionary any other way. The scoping is simple and clear: there is literally no legitimate use of those classes except in a single method call, but C# forces extra bug opportunities onto us :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, no inline implementation of classes in C#. There are only [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx), but they don't support adding interfaces (see for example [Can a C# anonymous class implement an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191013/can-a-c-sharp-anonymous-class-implement-an-interface)) (nor they support adding methods or fields... They only support properties).

You can use the methods of `System.Reflection.Emit` to generate a class at runtime, but it's long and tedious.

Comment: @ninjahedgehog There is non ninja-like tricky trick. Technically you could create a new class through Reflection, but it would be very much work. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733900/dynamically-creating-a-proxy-class

Comment: @ninjahedgehog If you want to accept a single-method interface (in your case one `void` method), instead accept an `Action`.

Comment: Damn and I was looking for a ninja alike tricky trick. A static method that does the job and I just have to set what interface I wish to inject as parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class that wraps an `Action` and implements that interface:

```
public sealed class SomeAction : ISomeInterface
{
    Action action;
    public SomeAction (Action action) { this.action = action; }
    public void DoIt() { this.action(); }
}
```

This allows you to use it as follows:

```
object.myMethod(new SomeAction(() => Console.WriteLine("yay"));
```

This is of course only very practical if you are going to reuse `SomeAction`, but this is probably the most convenient solution.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty common in java but there is no way you can do it in C#. You can pass a functions or procedures as parameters though:

```
public void myMethod(Action act)
{
    act();
}

myMethod( () => Console.WriteLine("yay") );
```

Several (generic) version of Action (procedure with parameters and no return value) and Func (functions with parameters and return value) exist.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the "ImpromptuInterface" NuGet package. 
With the combination of this package and ExpandoObject, you can do something like this

```
//Create an expando object and create & assign values to all the fields that exists in your interface
dynamic sigObj = new ExpandoObject();
sigObj.EmployeeKey = 1234;

//Create the object using "ActLike" method of the Impromptu class
INewSignatureAcquired sig = Impromptu.ActLike<INewSignatureAcquired>(sigObj);
```