# RealProxy in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, aop, dnx, .net-core

I'm working with the namespaces `System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies` and `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging` for AOP in C#.
I'm trying to port my application from .Net Framework 4.6 to dnxcore/dotnet core.

Intellisense says, that these two namespaces are not available with my framework-vesion (netcoreapp1.0 / dnxcore50). Any idea if these two namespaces will appear? or any idea how to get the AOP like with the `RealProxy`-class?

I don't want to use 3rd-party-libraries - I only want to use what .Net offers me.

Comment: did you find the solution to this???

Comment: @RafaelEnriquez untill today there is none implemented in asp net core 1. Maybe with 1.1 or 1.2. when I found something I'll post the answere here :)

Comment: So what is the solution to it?
Is https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/ compatible with .NetCore?

Comment: @HaseebJadoon I didn't test with the current version of netstandard/netcore/whatevernet - i wrote my own implementation for AOP. This post soon has his first birthday - but feel free to test with the current version and let us know whether it works or not :)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger i'm porting the spring.net to .net standard. Today di/ioc/aop are working. Some details you will see at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/issues/133

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[It looks like RealProxy won't come to .NET Core/Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4091). In the issue, a Microsoft developer suggests [DispatchProxy](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Reflection.DispatchProxy) as an alternative.

Also, some existing AOP frameworks may support .NET Core already or in the future (as seen in the comments on the question).

An alternative is the `DispatchProxy`, which has a wonderful example here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/aspect-oriented-programming-in-c-sharp-using-dispatchproxy/.

If we simplify the code, this is what we get:

```csharp
public class LoggingDecorator<T> : DispatchProxy
{
    private T _decorated;

    protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            LogBefore(targetMethod, args);

            var result = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);

            LogAfter(targetMethod, args, result);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is TargetInvocationException)
        {
            LogException(ex.InnerException ?? ex, targetMethod);
            throw ex.InnerException ?? ex;
        }
    }

    public static T Create(T decorated)
    {
        object proxy = Create<T, LoggingDecorator<T>>();
        ((LoggingDecorator<T>)proxy).SetParameters(decorated);

        return (T)proxy;
    }

    private void SetParameters(T decorated)
    {
        if (decorated == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(decorated));
        }
        _decorated = decorated;
    }

    private void LogException(Exception exception, MethodInfo methodInfo = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Class {_decorated.GetType().FullName}, Method {methodInfo.Name} threw exception:\n{exception}");
    }

    private void LogAfter(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] args, object result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Class {_decorated.GetType().FullName}, Method {methodInfo.Name} executed, Output: {result}");
    }

    private void LogBefore(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Class {_decorated.GetType().FullName}, Method {methodInfo.Name} is executing");
    }
}
```

So if we have an example class `Calculator` with a corresponding interface (not shown here):

```
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

we can simply use it like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var decoratedCalculator = LoggingDecorator<ICalculator>.Create(new Calculator());
    decoratedCalculator.Add(3, 5);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: So `DispatchProxy` is the way to go now. Thanks for sharing your knowledge. :)

Comment: Just commenting that targetMethod.Invoke uses reflection and is slow. Also it doesn't work with async method without jumping through some hoops that involve even more slower reflections. The method works, but really isn't too ideal tbh.

Comment: Sad. `DispatchProxy` can only work with interfaces but not with classes.

Answer (score 13):

You can use either `System.Reflection.DispatchProxy` or your own simple decorator implementations. Check [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) page on Wikipedia for implementation examples.

Currently in .NET Core, you can't use constructor injection with `DispatchProxy`. You have to use `DispatchProxy.Create()` factory method and property injection with explicit cast to proxy type that you want to use. For more information check [DispachProxyTest.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Reflection.DispatchProxy/tests/DispatchProxyTests.cs) in .NET Core GitHub repository.

This is an example of a simple generic decorator that inherits `DispatchProxy`:

```
class GenericDecorator : DispatchProxy
{
    public object Wrapped { get; set; }
    public Action<MethodInfo, object[]> Start { get; set; }
    public Action<MethodInfo, object[], object> End { get; set; }
    protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
    {
        Start?.Invoke(targetMethod, args);
        object result = targetMethod.Invoke(Wrapped, args);
        End?.Invoke(targetMethod, args, result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And its usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEcho toWrap = new EchoImpl();
        IEcho decorator = DispatchProxy.Create<IEcho, GenericDecorator>();
        ((GenericDecorator)decorator).Wrapped = toWrap;
        ((GenericDecorator)decorator).Start = (tm, a) => Console.WriteLine($"{tm.Name}({string.Join(',', a)}) is started");
        ((GenericDecorator)decorator).End = (tm, a, r) => Console.WriteLine($"{tm.Name}({string.Join(',', a)}) is ended with result {r}");
        string result = decorator.Echo("Hello");
    }

    class EchoImpl : IEcho
    {
        public string Echo(string message) => message;
    }

    interface IEcho
    {
        string Echo(string message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Castle.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Core) which supports .Net Core:

```cs
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ObservableProxyTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly ProxyGenerator Generator = new ProxyGenerator();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var obj = new MyEntity()
            {
                Name = "My name",
                Description = "My description"
            };

            var proxy = Generator.CreateClassProxyWithTarget(obj, new ObservableInterceptor());

            Console.WriteLine("Object changed: " + proxy.IsChanged);

            proxy.Name = "My name 2";
            proxy.Description = "My description 2";

            Console.WriteLine("Object changed: " + proxy.IsChanged);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal interface IObservable
    {
        bool IsChanged { get; }
        void SetChanged();
    }

    public abstract class BaseEntity : IObservable
    {
        public virtual bool IsChanged { get; protected set; }

        public void SetChanged()
        {
            IsChanged = true;
        }
    }

    public class MyEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        // Virtual keyword is very important
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ObservableInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var observable = invocation.InvocationTarget as IObservable;
            if (observable != null && !observable.IsChanged && IsSetter(invocation.Method))
            {
                observable.SetChanged();
            }
            invocation.Proceed();
        }

        private bool IsSetter(MethodInfo method)
        {
            return method.IsSpecialName && method.Name.StartsWith("set_", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
    }

}
```

Please also read very nice article: https://fullboarllc.com/change-tracking-structuremap-dynamicproxy/