# Web API with legacy code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-2.0

I will explain briefly my situation before asking for recommendations:

**Context**

Among other topics* I have been asked to develop a REST api that will be on the cloud (Azure)

The current (soon legacy) application works with windows service.

Behind this web API/windows service that receive the data and deserialize it (before serializing again when sending the response) there is Pricing Library which is used to compute data provided by custom-xml format.

**The problem**

I am quite concerned with compatibility issues as I keep encountering errors due to uncompatibilities from external libs with .NetCore 2.0

I had an issue with log4net as the Pricing Lib is using 1.2.13 version while 2.0.8 is already available. I solved this but I now encounter [RealProxy in dotnet core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467753/realproxy-in-dotnet-core) issue

I feel I will keep encountering new issues and it will be really time-consuming to fix them each time. But perhaps I am wrong since I only want to revamp the web API with .netcore 2 (not the pricing lib) ?

**My question**

Is it really profitable, performance wise, or functionally-wise, to switch now the web API to .NetCore 2.0 knowing that we call a Pricing Lib in 4.6.2 .Net Framework ? Is it worth to bother that much just to be using the trending framework while the former one is rather mature ?

Many thanks for your answers~ !

**PS:** I have already googled and read the relevant documentation, I am asking about experience from other users
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

*code optimization, configuring automatic build and deployment, markdown doc etc.

Comment: Because you said: _just to be using the trending framework_ - then answer will be no. If you don't have other arguments or benefits you expects from core 2, then stick with what you have.

Comment: But I am asking what could be the significant benefits compared to a more mature framework (4.6.2) :) Thank you for your reply anyways!

Comment: Common features of core 2 can be found by searching for them. What you want - is make a list of what "problems" you have with your current implementation and check does core 2 provide solution for them.