# Invoking method as wrapped object

Tags: c#, generics

With this class definition:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
  public T Item;

  public Wrapper(T item)
  {
    Item = item;
  }

  public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> wrapper)
  {
    return wrapper.Item;
  }

  public static implicit operator Wrapper<T>(T item)
  {
    return new Wrapper<T>(item);
  }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to invoke a method as the Item as the Wrapper object, without doing the obvious Wrapper.Item.Bar();

So rather than do this:

```
Wrapper<Foo> wrappedFoo = new Foo();
wrappedFoo.Item.Bar();
```

I want to do this:

```
Wrapper<Foo> wrappedFoo = new Foo();
wrappedFoo.Bar(); //equivalent to wrappedFoo.Item.Bar();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify the purpose? It looks more like you're looking for `interfaces` than generic wrappers.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by creating such a wrapper?

Comment: Yeah I can, I am using a more complicated class than the above one, which is a LRU Cache item.  The class has a last accessed time, and everytime we access Item we update the last accessed time.  I want to be able to make any type of object a LRU cache item, and have the LRU cache item be treated just like the item itself.

Comment: Is [this helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733900/dynamically-creating-a-proxy-class)?

Comment: Yes, that pointed me to the right direction, thank you!