# Calling a base method throws stackoverflow if derived class inherits from same interface

Tags: c#, inheritance

I would like to understand why this code runs into a `Stack Overflow`

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var docNode = new DocumentNode();
        docNode.Transactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction();
        
        var docNodeExt = new DocumentNodeExt();
        docNodeExt.Transactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction();
    }
}

public class DocumentNode : ITransactions
{
    void ITransactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction() => Console.WriteLine("ExecuteInvisibleTransaction in DocumentNode");
    public ITransactions Transactions => this;
}

public class DocumentNodeExt : DocumentNode, ITransactions
{       
    public void ExecuteInvisibleTransaction() => base.Transactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction();
}

public interface ITransactions
{
    void ExecuteInvisibleTransaction();
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/k4mJ5Y

But when I drop the interface `ITransactions` from the class `DocumentNodeExt` the `Stack Overflow` doesn't occure?

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var docNode = new DocumentNode();
        docNode.Transactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction();
        
        var docNodeExt = new DocumentNodeExt();
        docNodeExt.Transactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction();
    }
}

public class DocumentNode : ITransactions
{
    void ITransactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction() => Console.WriteLine("ExecuteInvisibleTransaction in DocumentNode");
    public ITransactions Transactions => this;
}

public class DocumentNodeExt : DocumentNode
{       
    public void ExecuteInvisibleTransaction() => base.Transactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction();
}

public interface ITransactions
{
    void ExecuteInvisibleTransaction();
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/g0JX58

Comment: Should have known better as to ask about stack overflow questions, on stack overflow....

Comment: Not exactly sure why was closed as "missing MRE" - code does indeed behaves the way described and behavior is not obvious at all.

Comment: You'd normally get a loud warning, suggesting that *new* is required to intentionally hide a base class method.  But that mechanism doesn't work with an explicit interface implementation in the mix.  Not exactly sure why it was written that way, consider *virtual*.

Comment: @HansPassant Is this really hiding? The parent method isn't named `ExecuteInvisibleTransaction`, it's named `ITransactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction`. I don't think the hiding-detection feature is designed to handle interface inheritance like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact line in the C# spec that addresses this, but as someone who's spent a lot of time looking at interface implementation rules in C# and IL, I conceptually have the rule that a **class method C.M may only implicitly implement an interface method I.M if C directly implements I or a descendant interface of I**.

In your first example, `DocumentNodeExt` directly implements `ITransactions`, so `DocumentNodeExt.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction` implicitly implements `ITransactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction`. To prove this, if you check [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQACfBhRROyAzLmpegOw4DeOhaqTBjexuAbgIYBOuGAHsAxgDlhMAKa4AvLgB20gO64AImICuAW2mLgkmQAoAlAG42xERKnSAdABV+vRQGdeo4GGHv7AUQAPaVEtYGkASUVuMDcwACMIaWdXDy8fRTNLTmIrIj5BGyNpIOB5JVUNbT0DYtKsvMIiu1KnF3dPb183AODQ8KiYuMTk9rSuzIs8gF8cWexSCipNUJrDO1wQXAiUjvTuhjzkABZt3fGMnqCQsMjo2ISk886Ms3kAPmoATmMAImv+ncho9RqkXr5cGBFFVVvp1jJflMcpQKDsxuD3LhnvtMXJPsAABaxbLzRaUVAw3RwuqBMpbFZU2p2KBndE4twMLhHJanAG3QYPEbYiZvPG4eK8NwOYWXXo3Ab3YZPNkipGk7DkSEGaT8ABmnlkaLB7MOyJOuD5CuBQpVrzVQA) you'll see that the class method is marked `virtual` on the IL side.

Thus, here's what happens to cause the stack overflow:

1. Calling `docNodeExt.Transactions` results in an implicit conversion of `docNodeExt` to `DocumentNode` (as `DocumentNodeExt` doesn't define that property), so the getter called is `DocumentNode.Transactions`, which produces the same object as `docNodeExt`, implicitly converted to `ITransactions`.
2. Calling `ExecuteInvisibleTransaction` on that instance of `ITransactions` leads to `DocumentNodeExt.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction` being called, as that is the [most specific implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#the-most-specific-override-rule) of that interface method for the underlying class type.
3. Which calls `base.Transactions` - `base` meaning the type `DocumentNode` - resulting in the same object as determined in step 1.
4. Calling `ExecuteInvisibleTransaction` on that instance of `ITransactions` does the same thing as step 2. Repeat steps 2, 3, and 4 until you run out of space on the stack. (Unbounded recursion.)

In your second example, `DocumentNodeExt` does *not* directly implement `ITransactions`, so `DocumentNodeExt.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction` does not implicitly implement `ITransactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction`. It's just a non-virtual class method that happens to have the same name and signature. Comment out the `, ITransactions` part in the sharplab link above and now the IL will no longer say the class method is `virtual`.

Thus, in step 2 above, instead of the most specific implementation being `DocumentNodeExt.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction`, it is the explicit implementation in `DocumentNode`. This terminates with calling `Console.WriteLine`, so there's no unbounded recursion.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `base` keyword is special. The `base` keyword changed the lookup rules on the **immediately following term** and only on that.

Look:

```
base.Transactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction()
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^
     only here       nope
```

Since the derived class doesn't provide its own `Transactions` property, the `base.Transactions` is exactly the same as `this.Transactions`. And here we have it. The `ExecuteInvisibleTransaction` is then called on whatever object `Transactions` returned, and, well, it's the same `this` (as implemented in the base).

From how the code looks like, I see that what you intended, was to call the base `ExecuteInvisibleTransaction`, not the base `Transactions`. But `base` doesn't work like that. It only works on the immediate term, only at the first `.` dot after `base`.

Write:

```
base.Transactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction()
```

think:

```
(base.Transactions).ExecuteInvisibleTransaction()
```

EDIT:

I just noticed that my explanation doesn't cover the second part, and yeah, it's about that dual-implementation of ITransaction, like JoeSewell explained. In a bit simpler wording:

- normal implementation of an interface, implicitly makes that method `virtual`, so derived classes re-implementing that interface will "just bind" to the base, and calling that method via interface will pick the "latest" implementation (from the "furthest" child class that provided its own version)
- buuut.. explicit implementation is special. It's private-ish, so it can't be virtual

Therefore, what Joe said. In first case, `base.Transactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction` called `(virtual ITransactions.ExecuteInvisibleTransaction`, hence the one from child class..

Thanks Joe for very detailed answer!